# How to link 2 files in Cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have researched this on Internet but I either don't understand the answers or the previous questions don't address my problem.

I have 3 files A,B,C, where C is the executable and A,B just some library code I write myself. B depends on A. C depends on B and A. How do I properly link them in Cmake? I tried this:

```
add_library(A A.c)
add_library(B B.c)
add_executable(C C.c)
target_link_libraries(B A)
target_link_libraries(C B A)
```

Despite that I still get the "undefined reference to xxx" error. I really don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Impossible to say what could be wrong without also seeing the code and the specific error.

Comment: @SeanBurton I'm not able to show the code unfortunately but the error is exactly like I say: in file B, it calls a function defined in file A and I get the error "undefined reference to 'xxx'" from file B when building.

Comment: It seems like the problem is not CMake's because when I compile all 3 files to object files and link with gcc I still get the same error. ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the culprit. I accidentally wrote an include guard in my source file. So all of my functions gets deleted by the preprocessor. After deleting the guard it works normally again.